# SchemaCrawler Row Count with Velocity template?

Tags: schemacrawler

Is it possible to get table row count with velocity template?

If anyone has done it before can you share howTo?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please use SchemaCrawler 16.6.1 (or better), which introduces a new command-line switch, `--load-row-counts`. (Please download both Velocity and Thymeleaf using the SchemaCrawler download tool first.) Then, you can use a Velocity template something like this:

```
#foreach($table in $catalog.tables)
#if ($table.tableType == "table")
$table.fullName - $table.getAttribute("schemacrawler.table.row_count")
#end
#end
```

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](https://www.schemacrawler.com/)